# Regarding the cardinality of orbits of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

This is a question from Dummit and Foote, and I am unsure about the justification regarding the last part of the statement regarding the cardinality.

The setting is:
Assume $G$ acts transitively on a finite set $A$ and let $H$ be a normal subgroup
        of $G$. Let $\mathcal{O}_1, ..., \mathcal{O}_r$ be the distinct orbits of $H$ on $A$.

Then, I have shown that $G$ acts transitively on the orbits. And, I would like to justify that they are of the same cardinality.

My argument is:
Take $\mathcal{O}_i, \mathcal{O}_j \in \{ \mathcal{O}_i \}_{i=1}^{r}$.
            Since $G$ acts transitively on the set of orbits, there exists $g \in G$ such that
            $\mathcal{O}_j = g\mathcal{O}_i$. We have $\mathcal{O}_i = H \cdot a \subset A$ 
            for some $a \in A$. Then, the transitive action of $G$ on $A$ gives a bijection
            $\sigma_g: A \rightarrow A$, $\sigma_g(a) = g \cdot a$ for every $g \in G$.
            Since $H \cdot a \subset A$, we have $|H \cdot a| = |\sigma_g(H \cdot a)| 
   = |g \cdot (H \cdot a)|$. Hence, $|\mathcal{O}_i| = |\mathcal{O}_j|$.

Is the argument sound?
Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you overcomplicating things. $O_i = gO_j$ immediately gives you a bijection between $O_i$ and$O_j$ with $x \mapsto gx$.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I am new to abstract algebra. So I tend to lack intuition and confidence in my response many times. Thanks!